# Kotlin - RxJava Subscribe doesn't trigger whene there is an event

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

I Initialize Publish Subject Rx Java in my activity like this

```
    private var publisher = PublishSubject.create<Int>()
```

And I try to create simple publish onNext like this in a button :

```
binding.btnFab.setOnClickListener {
        publisher.onNext(99)
    }
```

I try to listen the changes in function

```
CompositeDisposable().add(publisher.ofType(Int::class.java).subscribe(
        {
            "ON NEXT ${it}"
        },
        {
            "ON ERROR"
        },
        {
            "ON COMPLETE"
        }
    ))
```

But there is no one data that come out from my subscribe? do i make a mistake

Comment: The `ofType` filter is not needed. But what are those string literals in your observer supposed to achieve? As such they are quite much no-op. Forgot some kind of a print call?

Comment: Check if CompositeDisposable().isDisposed returns true, meaning anything you add to it will immediately get disposed, hence no notification will reach the observer.